# Facebook, Google OAuth fails sometimes on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth, azure-web-app-service

I am using Asp.Net MVC OAuth login with facebook and google and strange thing that at some period it doesnot work

```
var externalIdentity =
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                    .Authentication.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
if (loginInfo == null)
{
   return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

Seems here it cant get user info and redirect to login page. I cant figure out why or what can cause that. 
I also have two slots beta and production.

So any suggestion or maybe somebody already have that and found way how to fix that?

Comment: You may have different Website URL Register on Facebook  For Test and production application have you check this URL

Comment: @Saineshwar facebook and google will show error that sorry you try to redirect to wrong url or smth like that, and it works at some period of time

Comment: Please check this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218062/google-oauth-login-works-locally-fails-on-production-server?rq=1

Comment: It occurs every time or sometimes it runs and sometimes not

Comment: @MohitVerma It was first what i did since I remember i had issues with AzureStorage and problem was with time. So unfortunately its not this one :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after few weeks i solve my problem. Its really something strange and probably issue is because of azure, since beforemy implementation works on VMvare for 6 month.

in AccountController there is method

```
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
```

add there

```
Session.RemoveAll();
```

PS/ Firstly when I have seen this recommendation I did not understood how it can help but then next time when OAuth fails i just simply restarted WebApp and it starts working. By the way even now i dont understand what is going on with session but it works.