# GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo() returns null

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0

I have written a generic owin middleware using oauth-2.0.
I have added reference of that in asp.net web forms.The middleware is returning user identity once the user is authenticated and am trying to access in RegisterExternalLogin.aspx.cs  using

```
var loginInfo = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo();
```

which is coming as null.
Please share if anyone has pointer on this issue.

Comment: I deleted my comment since it was not a solution you can check solution on my post, i had the same issue and after few month i have fixed that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751137/facebook-google-oauth-fails-sometimes-on-azure-production

Answer (score 0):

In your AccountController and ManageController try to add:

```
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session.RemoveAll();
```

Also try to create a session when you start your application

```
Session["value"] = 0;
```